# How do I make the border of my image along the curve?

Tags: html, css

I made a JS Fiddle in which I embed an image with rounded corners.

http://jsfiddle.net/JDRSc/

Here is the CSS for the img tag.

```
img {
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}​
```

How do I make the border of the image follow the curve of the rounded corners? Right now, the image itself still has sharp corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, http://jsfiddle.net/JDRSc/7/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://kittens-for-sale.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/kittens-for-sale-5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

​**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 10px solid black;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px; /*Sum of #wrapper border + img border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; /*Sum of #wrapper border + img border-radius*/
    border-radius: 30px; /*Sum of #wrapper border + img border-radius*/
}    

img {
    display: block;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

To manage the border radius to take effect inside and outside, you should give a value of border-radius to be more than the border-size.

This will fix it.

Try:

```
border-size:10px;
border-radius:15px;
```

it will work.

Comment: Well, i couldn't find any document or reference about that yet.. but its a math issue. When the radius is 20, the center of radius will be 20px. This means the center will not be rounded. Here is something may explain some: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

Comment: @DavidFaux What browser are you using? Older Firefoxes, like 3.5, act like you describe, i.e. the image itself has square corners and the black border goes behind it. It's fine in the latest Firefox though.

Comment: I am using Firefox 13 and Chrome. Works fine for me.